# problem in finding weekday for date in logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash

`2019-08-07T10:38:52-04:00` This is a date that I have in my data. I need to get the weekday of the date which should be `Wednesday`, but I got the value  as `Thursday` instead.

```
date { 
  match => [ "date_time", ISO8601 ]
  target => "[@metadata][date_time]"
}

ruby {
  code => '
    t = Time.at(event.get("[@metadata][date_time]").to_i)
    d = DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
    event.set("date_wday", d.strftime("%A"))
  '
}
```

I got `Thursday` from that code. Can any one help me out with that code to get the weekday to that date as `Wednesday`.

Comment: What is the time zone of the machine? Interesting issue.

Comment: The time zone of that machine is EST , Michiel.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives me the correct result:

```
date {
  match => [ "[date_time]", "ISO8601" ]
  target => "[@metadata][date_time]"
}

ruby {
  code => "event.set('date_wday', DateTime.parse(event.get('[@metadata][date_time]').to_s).strftime('%A'))"
}
```